# Booting from UEFI

Tags: boot, uefi

I have a Gigabyte board with UEFI, and I can't get an OS up and running. Unfortunately, this product supports booting from neither USB nor CDROM. I've built a SSD with the most recent version of Ubuntu on VirtualBox in UEFI mode. I believe the problem is that I don't know the right path for either the EFI boot or the kernel. The following questions appear in the UEFI boot loader.

```
File path of the EFI Application or the kernel: 
Is your application an OS loader? [y/n]:
Arguments to pass to the EFI Application:
Description for this new Entry: 
File path of the EFI Application or the kernel:
```

Alternatively, the solution could be just to install a different OS per a different set of instructions.

Thoughts?

Comment: Ubuntu, and most of it's derivatives like Mint, support UEFI booting 'out of the box'... How are you making your USB boot device and what options are you given when you open the boot menu? Note you may need to disable "secure boot" in the EFI/BIOS before it will allow booting or even showing in the boot menu from an insecure device

Comment: The problem is that part of the boot configuration is stored in NVRAM rather than the disk. Is there any particular reason why you chose to install Ubuntu in a VM first?

Comment: @acejavelin, I'm making an SDD, not USB, but I think the difference is semantic. I turned UEFI on in VirtualBox and installed an OS on the SDD. I haven't found the option for either Secure or Fast boots in this UEFI implementation. In terms of the options given, there are a host of menus, but the bootloader menu has grub, shell and boot manager menus until I add the appropriate loader in boot manager which gives the aforementioned menu.

Comment: @user121330 Why not just install the standard way and customize as needed?

Comment: @DanielB I'm open to suggestions. As USB and CDROM boots aren't supported and the PXE server boot didn't work, I figured making a boot disk in a UEFI VirtualBox would give me the appropriate partitioning etc...

Comment: @acejavelin, I'm sorry I'm being unclear. I understand the 'standard way' to install an OS to be plugging in a USB drive or inserting a CD, turning the computer on and following instructions. Those two options are not yet supported by this hardware. I'm assuming that you read what I wrote and that 'standard way' is something different from that. What is the 'standard way'?

Comment: @user121330 Why on earth would you NOT be able to boot some kind of removable media. I think we need more information to help you, the specific motherboard you have, the installation iso, and what media you want to use. This isn't a jump through hoops thing, this is fairly simple process

Comment: @acejavelin I completely agree that I should be able to boot from removable media. Unfortunately, this product does not yet support those functions. This isn't hardware that anybody would be familiar with even if I could disclose more than I have. I used the Ubuntu server install on a SSD (OCZ, plenty big for an OS). I wish this really was a fairly simple process. I'm going to try a Fedora install next.

Comment: @user121330 I can guess at your situation and have been in your shoes, I won't press that issue anymore. If your using an experimental platform or development sample, consider contacting your inside engineering rep... If that's not possible, could you do a basic installation on a similar platform to the ssd then just move it to your engineering platform?

Comment: @acejavelin, I only have this board. In searching the internet, I've seen similar challenges with UEFI booting (but, obviously no solutions as I'm here), so I thought perhaps somebody would be familiar with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Booting in EFI mode from an internal hard disk involves storing the boot loader as a file *with an arbitrary name* on the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) on the hard disk. Because the filename is not fixed or pre-determined (with an exception, noted shortly), the firmware needs to know what that filename is, and that information is stored in NVRAM. Because the NVRAM doesn't get transferred when you move a disk from one computer to another, installing an OS using one computer and then trying to boot that OS on another computer will not work -- or at least, you must jump through some extra hoops to get it to work. Possible ways to recover include:

- **Move or copy the boot loader to the fallback filename** -- To enable booting OS installers and emergency tools, EFI supports a *fallback filename,* which is `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on the ESP (for x86-64 systems; the name varies from one architecture to another). You can copy or move your OS's boot loader to this name and it will probably work. There can be complications, though, if the boot loader hard-codes paths to its configuration or support files. As a general rule, this makes copying the entire directory to `EFI/BOOT` and then renaming the boot loader to `bootx64.efi` the safest approach.
- **Boot temporarily with a "boot from file" option** -- Some EFIs offer an option to boot from a file on a one-time basis. You can use this option to get the system started, and then register the boot loader with the firmware in some other way.
- **Use a boot manager that scans for boot loaders** -- Some boot managers, such as my own [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) scan for boot loaders when they start. Using such a boot manager on a CD-R or USB flash drive can get you up and running, much like the preceding option. You'd then want to register your regular boot loader (or possibly install rEFInd to the hard disk).
- **Register the boot loader** -- In Linux, the `efibootmgr` utility registers boot loaders with the NVRAM. In Windows, you can use the built-in `bcdedit` or third-party [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) to do the job. Some EFIs let you create entires using their own user interfaces. You'll probably want to register your boot loader in this way if you use a temporary measure to get started on a one-time basis.

The name of the OS's boot loader is somewhat unpredictable. Most OSes place their boot loaders in subdirectories of `EFI` named after themselves, like `EFI/Microsoft` for Windows or `EFI/fedora` for Fedora. The name of the boot loader could be anything. You mentioned Ubuntu, though; for it, you'd launch or register `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` (if Secure Boot is enabled, or optionally if it's not enabled) or `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` (if Secure Boot is not enabled).